# Invalid object name when trying to insert into newly-created temporary SQL Server table from Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a temporary table in Microsoft SQL Server, then insert data into it, then return the data to Python as a dataframe, preferably.

Here is my connection, which works fine (password hidden).

```
EKA = turbodbc.connect(dsn='ekaprd', uid='smccarth', pwd='*****', database="Eka", turbodbc_options = turbodbc.make_options(prefer_unicode=True))
```

Here is the SQL string I want to run:

```
sql_string = """

create table #retaildeals 
(
     TransactionType varchar(10),
     TCID int,
     TID int,
     ItemID int,
     strategyID int,
     Commodity varchar(10),
     BuyOrSell varchar(10),
     Category varchar(50)
)

insert into #retaildeals
select 
     'Physical',
     ti.TransactingCompanyID,
     ti.TransactionID,
     ti.TransactionItemID,
     th.strategyID,
     tpd.Commodity,
     tpd.BuyOrSell,
     isnull(tci.categoryvalue, '')
from TransactionHeader TH (nolock)   
inner join strategy S (nolock)
       on s.StrategyID = th.StrategyID
inner join transactionitem TI (nolock)
       on th.TransactingCompanyID = ti.TransactingCompanyID
       and th.TransactionID = ti.TransactionID
inner join TransactionPhysicalDetail TPD (nolock)        
       on tpd.TransactingCompanyID = ti.TransactingCompanyID
       and tpd.TransactionID = ti.TransactionID
       and tpd.TransactionItemID = ti.TransactionItemID
inner join TransactionCategory TC (nolock)
       on tc.TransactingCompanyID = th.TransactingCompanyID
       and tc.TransactionID = th.TransactionID
left join TransactionCategoryItem TCI (nolock)
       on tc.CategoryItemID1 = tci.CategoryItemID
where
 th.IsVoid = 0
 and ti.IsVoid = 0
 and th.transactiontypeid in (50, 53)
group by
 ti.TransactingCompanyID,
 ti.TransactionID,
 ti.TransactionItemID,
 th.strategyID,
 tpd.commodity,
 tpd.BuyOrSell,
 isnull(tci.categoryvalue, '')
"""
```

Finally, I try to execute the query string:

```
cursor = EKA.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_string)
```

And I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: ODBC error
state: 42S02
native error code: 208
message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#retaildeals'.
```

The above SQL code works fine when I execute it in programs such as Aqua Data Studio, or as a passthrough query in SAS. Why doesn't it work when done in Python?

Comment: You might try a module other than turbodbc for troubleshooting. If that works, report the issue to the [turbodbc GitHub project](https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues) or use a different module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `[enmax].[smccarth].[#retaildeals]` instead of just `#retaildeals`.